# Access is Denied - Get Permissions from BIM 360 API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am receiving the following response when sending a Get Req per the GET Permissions endpoint (see link to the Documentation below):
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-permissions-GET/

REQUEST:

```
    resp = requests.get('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/docs/v1/projects/'+project_id+'/folders/'+folder_id+'/permissions', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ tok})
```

The Auth token (tok) is received via 3-legged Authentication with scope = data:read. This is the response that is received:

> {"code": "ERR_AUTHORIZATION_ERROR", "title": "The access is denied", "detail": "The access is denied on resource <account_id>"}

Any assistance is appreciated!

Thanks,
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that the user must have permission for accessing the information required.

As specified [in the documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-permissions-GET/):

"If you are calling this endpoint on behalf of a user, the user needs to have VIEW permissions for the folder."